# c# winform windows media player playing only audio no video

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on a project and want to play a video from my computer with window media player on a window form , but its only playing audio and no video , i have added the wmp.dll

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\d1.mp4";
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymXMD.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce, it work fine for me with an .mp4 file *that has video*.  When I make an .mp4 with *only audio*, I get what your screenshot contains, so are you sure your .mp4 has video?

Comment: yes i tried everything .mp4 . mov .avi  i even tried to get vlc but still didnt work